# Какие проекты можно создать на monotouch?

Tags: mono, monotouch, monodroid, c#

Доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы узнать возможно ли с помощью mono создать полноценные игры, приложения для мобильных устройств? Или это лишь затравка для создание просты приложений? Возможно ли с помощью mono делать полноценные игры с физикой и анимацией? Если да, то как это делается.. Например openGl, что то похожее на XNA? Если можно со ссылками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть [MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame)(Бывший XnaTouch), есть аналогичный [ExEn](http://rockethub.com/projects/752-exen-xna-for-iphone-android-and-silverlight), тоже еще одна реализация Xna под MonoTouch.

А самое интересное, скоро должен выйти [DeltaEngine](http://deltaengine.net/), очень крутой движок покрывающий практически все платформы.